# Spring boot app (docker container) - Eden space utilization(EU) keeps increasing slowly (without any traffic)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I have a docker container(max memory allocated 512MB) having a spring boot app running, where the Eden space utilization(EU) keeps increasing slowly (without any traffic).

This spring boot app is using openjdk-11, G1 garbage collector with Xms 128MB and Xmx 256MB

After I deploy it, and don't push any traffic/request to it, the Eden space utilization keeps increasing slowly with time.
This is on a VM where I have limited access and can see Eden space utilization(EU) value using command

```
jstat -gc
```

I dont have permission to run the docker stats on the shared VM machine, though have access to my container logs, but can see all values on the Grafana like `container_memory_usage_bytes`, `container_memory_rss`.
I tried to do go through the heapdumps (after importing to Visual VM) but not able to figure out any leaks or patterns which can cause increase in heap space

Looking for suggestions: where should I focus to debug it better

Note:`YGC(young generation GC)` and `CGC(Concurrent GC)` events occurs and does not cause any OOM errors etc, and there is slight increase in `Old space capacity as well as Utilization` with YGC (means most objects are garbage collected and few moved to Old space)